# How to download packages from a non-native-arch repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I'm trying to download a package from Raspbian repository using a Kubuntu x86_64 machine. Here's what I tried:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/\
 jessie main contrib non-free rpi' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
wget https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.public.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt-get update
apt-get download libqt4-dev:armhf
```

All the commands before the last one succeed (modulo not finding armhf packages in Ubuntu repositories and amd64 ones in Raspbian repo). But the last command gives me the following error:

> E: Can't select candidate version from package libqt4-dev:armhf as it has no candidate

What am I missing? How can I make `apt-get` locate the package from the new repository?

Comment: run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf` and the redo the apt download

Comment: @lnee how is it different from what I reported to have tried?

Comment: did not read sry